# Is $\int f$ on [0,1] always equal to $\int f$ on [x,1] when take the limit of x to 0

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Is $\int f$ on [0,1] always equal to $\int f$ on [x,1] when take the limit of x to 0? I know that if f is nonnegative, then I can use LMCT to prove it. However, how about f is only bounded, or only the later integral exists and finite? I suspect that if this always holds.

Comment: You have to prove that $\int_0^xf(x)dx\rightarrow 0$. If $f(x)$ is bounded by $M$, then this it's fairly easy to show that this integral is between $-xM,xM$. May I ask what definition of integral of an unbounded function do you take?

Comment: @Wojowu Here use Lebesgue integral, i.e. for a nonnegative function f, integration is taking the supremum of all functions h smaller or equal to f and h is bounded on a finite measure.

Answer (score 0):

It reduces to showing that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \int_0^x f(y) dy = 0$. This is trivial in the (proper) Riemann framework, where all functions are assumed bounded. In the Lebesgue framework it requires an approximation step, e.g. the bounded convergence theorem or the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: I see. Here I want to prove it in the Lebesgue framework. And I can see that f is bounded can infer to the equality. However, is the second integration is finite is sufficient to give the equality?

Comment: @PeterLiu There are different ways to approach it in the unbounded Lebesgue context. A straightforward one is to use dominated convergence: you are integrating $f \chi_{[0,x]}$ whose magnitude is at most $|f|$ which is assumed integrable, so you can interchange pointwise limit and integration to get zero. But this sort of result is somewhat more basic than dominated convergence, so you may not yet have that at your disposal.

Comment: Here is a problem that f may be not integrable. Is the second integration is finite enough to show it is integrable?

Comment: @PeterLiu Do you mean, if $f$ is integrable on every $[x,1]$, can you conclude that is integrable on $[0,1]$? The answer to that is no, consider $f(x)=1/x$ on $(0,1]$ and arbitrarily define it at zero. There is essentially no way around explicitly assuming integrability on the whole interval.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right. Then I think I can't use dominated convergence since the dominated function may be not integrable. How can I get the conclusion?

Comment: @PeterLiu In general you can't, as the example I just showed indicates. You need further assumptions, which might depend on the problem at hand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37287/discussion-between-peter-liu-and-ian).